# Javascript if condition with return

Tags: javascript

Folks, I am modifying a current function slightly to make use of two
variables. I have shown the past and present versions in the code snippet. 
Basically what I want is if either one of the  two `if conditions` namely **First Condition** and **Second Condition** are 
are true, do not execute the remaining logic of the function. If both are false, continue with the remaining code of the function. 
 I think I am making a 
silly mistake somewhere and if the first condition is true, execution is stopping right there. 
(I Know that is because of the return statement at the end.)
How do I make sure the second if condition as well even if first one was true and returned a `return`

```
function myAlgorithm(code1, code2) {

   if(eval(code1)) {

      if(First condition) {
         alert("You cant continue");

         return;
      }
    }

    if(eval(code2)) {
       if(Second condition){
         alert("You cant continue");
       return;
      }

    }

    //If both of the above if conditions say "You cant continue", then only
    //disrupt the function execution, other wise continue with the left
    //logic

    //Rest of the function logic goes here

}
```

**Ealier this code used to be:**

```
function myAlgorithm() {

   if((First Condition) && (Second Condition)){
    alert("You cant continue");

    return;
   }

  //Rest of the function logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Do you want to eval both `code1` and `code2`, no matter which conditions are true? And did you notice that the `return` in the second `if` is placed *after* the closing brace?

Comment: Have you tried by doing return True; or return 1; in place of those empty return;

Comment: @SLaks, because code1 and code2 are strings.

Comment: @Yogu, Fixed the return. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Mangobug, I didnt try. Should I return 1 from both and later on check for 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable and increment it once the condition is met. Then check to see if the variable was incremented.

```
function myAlgorithm(code1, code2) {
    var count = 0;
    if (eval(code1)) {

        if (First condition) {
            alert("You cant continue");

            count++;
        }
    }

    if (eval(code2)) {
        if (Second condition) {
            alert("You cant continue");
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 2) {
        return "both conditions met";
    }

    //If both of the above if conditions say "You cant continue", then only
    //disrupt the function execution, other wise continue with the left
    //logic
    //Rest of the function logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Truth.. Let me try this real quick.

Answer (score 0):

Could use flag variables to keep track of your conditions and then check both of them like before

```
function myAlgorithm(code1, code2) {
 var flag1;
 var flag2
if(eval(code1)) {
  flag1 = First condition
}

if(eval(code2)) {
  flag2 = second condition
}

if(flag1 && flag2){
  return;
}
//If both of the above if conditions say "You cant continue", then only
//disrupt the function execution, other wise continue with the left
//logic

//Rest of the function logic goes here

}
```

Comment: Thanks Decad.. I'll try this one as well.

Comment: oops someone downgraded your solution... Folks can someone explain why?